# Upgrade to MySQL 8. Unknown character set index for field '255' received from server. Exception

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

The mysql5 db has been used to *latin1* and *latin1_general_ci* character encoding settings, all tables are used also this character set.

After migration to mysql8(create and restore dump from mysql5-to-mysql8) the error:  **Unknown character set index for field '255' received from server.** occurs when doing connection to db.

Why does it happens?, I suppose that it may be related with a fact that mysql8 uses  **utf8mb4** character set encoding as a default.

But *utf8mb4* encoding is more wide than *latin1* so it must to be support to migration from latin1(**1Byte**) to utf8mb4(**4Bytes**) not vice verse.

The changing character set of the db to **latin1** and collation to **latin1_swedish_ci** doesn't take affect.

There is some mysql8 params:

> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\
```

MySql8 connector driver is:

```
mysql-connector-java v. 3.1.14
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue when I am executing scripts from my Java application. It is showing the same error as mentioned in the subject line.

The fix is(in my case,as we earlier use latin1): provide character encoding type in connection url.

```
?characterEncoding=latin1
```

Here is the list of available types which are used between [java and mysql](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-j-8.0-en.pdf). This is the official documentation of java-mysql connector jar.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution for this problem is
download the latest version of connector from the following website..
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

When you go there there was a option to select operating system if you use windows then select the platform independent option then a download option appears ... download the zip file and extract it.Then go to your project and add this jar file into the libraries.So that's all your problem will be solved.
Hope this solution work for you...

Comment: Just Copied the jar file and paste without changing name or anything, It's Worked !!! :) Thanks a lot Man !